# regular expressions - match only if entire line is contained in match

Tags: regex

Let's say I have the following text:

```
abcdabcd
abcdabcdabcd
abcdabcdabcdabcd
etc...
```

I only want a match if the entire line is only made out of even number of 'abcd' occurrences.
meaning the first and third line should match and the second should not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`^(abcdabcd)+$` expression should work.